# Shiny app not working after being split into modules

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinymodules

I have the following shiny app that works correctly in app.R/ui.R-server.R. The main idea is that an user submit a dataset and then the app can highlight some errors in the dataset (i.e., incorrect data formats, ranges, etc.), so the user can modify them directly in the app or download the data. However, when I split the app in different modules and functions, the app is not working anymore. I think the issue is related to how I try to access to df$data in the different modules but I am not entirely sure.

Code to built a df(.xlsx) to be submitted in the app:

```
df_submitted <- data.frame(x=c(1:20),y=c(0:1),z=c("R"))
df_submitted[[2,2]] <- 3
df_submitted[[5,2]] <- "yes"
df_submitted[[6,2]] <- "no"
df_submitted[[3,3]] <- "python"
```

Single file app (working)

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)
library(validate)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)
library(jsonlite)


ui <- (fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Test"),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("df_submitted","Upload your file",accept = c(".xlsx")),
    downloadButton("download","Download"),
    actionButton("lab_num","Replace Labels")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("dt_data"))
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  
  #Upload file
  df_uploaded <- reactive({
    file_submitted <- input$df_submitted
    file_ext <- tools::file_ext(file_submitted$name)
    file_path <- file_submitted$datapath

    if (is.null(file_submitted)){
      return(NULL)
    } else if (file_ext=="xlsx"){
      read_xlsx(file_path,sheet=1)
    }
  })

  observe({
    df$data <- df_uploaded()
  })
  
  ###Validate form
  data_validated <- reactive({
    req(df$data)
    df_validate <- df$data
    ##rules
    rules <- validator(
      x>5,
      y<3,
      z=="R"
    )
    #Confront rules against df
    out <- confront(df_validate,rules)
    cells_dt <- data.frame(values(out))
    cells_dt <- cells_dt %>%
      mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(x==TRUE,0,1))
    #Join cells that fail the rules for future highlight in TD
    df_validate <- cbind(df_validate,cells_dt)
    df_validate
  })
  
  #Render DT  
  output$dt_data=renderDT({
    df_dt <- data_validated()
    visible_cols <- 1:((ncol(df_dt)/2))
    hidden_cols <- ((ncol(df_dt)/2)+1):ncol(df_dt)
    
    df_dt %>%
      datatable(
        editable="cell",
        selection="none",
        options=list(
          autoWidth=T,
          columnDefs=list(list(targets=hidden_cols,visible=F)))) %>%
      formatStyle(visible_cols,hidden_cols,
                  backgroundColor=styleEqual(c(0,1),c("white","#FFC7CE")),
                  color=styleEqual(c(0,1),c("black","#9C0006")))
  },server=T) #End render DT
  
  dt_proxy <- dataTableProxy("dt_data")


  observeEvent(input$dt_data_cell_edit, {
    info <- input$dt_data_cell_edit
    df$data <<- editData(df$data,info,dt_proxy)
  })
  
#Button to automatically replace some patterns
  df_match <- data.frame(lab=c("Yes","No"),val=c(1,0))
  
  observeEvent(input$lab_num,{
    df$data <- df$data %>%
      mutate(y = case_when(
       y %in% df_match$lab ~ as.character(df_match$val[match(y,df_match$lab)]),
        TRUE~y))
  })
  
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename= function(){
      paste0("revised_",input$df_submitted)
    },
    content=function(file){
      df_tbl <- df$data
      write.xlsx(df_tbl,file,rowNames=F)
    })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Code split in modules. I am just putting the examples of some modules, ideally, I would like to have most of the code in modules/functions, but as is not working correctly, I am just putting some examples.

Module to download the data (it should be reactive, but the code is not working)

```
#Download ui button
downExcelUI <- function(id,label) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  downloadButton(ns("download"),label)
}

#Download Excel unformat server
downExcelUnformatServer <- function(id,filename,df) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input,output,session) {
     output$id <- downloadHandler(
      filename=filename,
      content=function(file){
        write.xlsx(df(),file,rowNames=F) #Based on my search, I should have the df as reactive(), but this is not working, if I removed () the df that is downloaded is not being reactive
      })
  })
}
```

#Module render DT, not being reactive

```
#Download ui button
renderDTUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("dt_table"))
}

#Download Excel unformat server
renderDTServer <- function(id,df) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input,output,session) {
    
    output$dt_table=renderDT({
      df_dt <- df()
      visible_cols <- 1:((ncol(df_dt)/2))
      hidden_cols <- ((ncol(df_dt)/2)+1):ncol(df_dt)
      
      df_dt %>%
        datatable(
          editable="cell",
          selection="none",
          options=list(
            autoWidth=T,
            columnDefs=list(list(targets=hidden_cols,visible=F)))) %>%
        formatStyle(visible_cols,hidden_cols,
                    backgroundColor=styleEqual(c(0,1),c("white","#FFC7CE")),
                    color=styleEqual(c(0,1),c("black","#9C0006")))
    },server=T)
    

  })
}
```

Function to validate the data. In the current example I have this function #commented# and I access directly in the server because if I use this function in the example nothing is displayed.

```
validation <- function(df){
  reactive({
    req(df())
    df_validate <- df()
    ##rules
    rules <- validator(
      x>5,
      y<3,
      z=="R"
    )
    #Confront rules against df
    out <- confront(df_validate,rules)
    cells_dt <- data.frame(values(out))
    cells_dt <- cells_dt %>%
      mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(x==TRUE,0,1))
    #Join cells that fail the rules for future highlight in DT
    df_validate <- cbind(df_validate,cells_dt)
    df_validate
  })
}
```

App.R

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)
library(validate)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)
library(jsonlite)


ui <- (fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Test"),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("df_submitted","Upload your file",accept = c(".xlsx")),
    downExcelUI("download_dt","Download"),
    actionButton("lab_num","Replace Labels")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    renderDTUI("dt_data"))
  
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  
  #Upload file
  df_uploaded <- reactive({
    file_submitted <- input$df_submitted
    file_ext <- tools::file_ext(file_submitted$name)
    file_path <- file_submitted$datapath

    if (is.null(file_submitted)){
      return(NULL)
    } else if (file_ext=="xlsx"){
      read_xlsx(file_path,sheet=1)
    }
  })

  observe({
    df$data <- df_uploaded()
  })
  
  #Function validate form, not working
  # data_validated <- validation(df$data)
  
  data_validated <- reactive({
    req(df$data)
    df_validate <- df$data
    ##rules
    rules <- validator(
      x>5,
      y<3,
      z=="R"
    )
    #Confront rules against df
    out <- confront(df_validate,rules)
    cells_dt <- data.frame(values(out))
    cells_dt <- cells_dt %>%
      mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(x==TRUE,0,1))
    #Join cells that fail the rules for future highlight in TD
    df_validate <- cbind(df_validate,cells_dt)
    df_validate
  })
  
  #Module Render DT
  df_renddt <- renderDTServer("dt_data",data_validated)
  
  dt_proxy <- dataTableProxy("df_renddt")

  observeEvent(input$df_renddt_cell_edit, {
    info <- input$df_renddt_cell_edit
    df$data <<- editData(df$data,info,dt_proxy)
  })
  
  #Replace data matching a specific value
  #Would like to have this in a function outside app.R as well
  df_match <- data.frame(lab=c("Yes","No"),val=c(1,0))
  observeEvent(input$lab_num,{
    df$data <- df$data %>%
      mutate(y = case_when(
       y %in% df_match$lab ~ as.character(df_match$val[match(y,df_match$lab)]),
        TRUE~y))
  })
  
  #Module download data
  downExcelUnformatServer("download_dt","form.xlsx",df$data)
} 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You need to supply us with some test data because your validation rules are very specific.

Comment: Hi Limey thank you for your comment. The test data can be reproduced using this code that I mentioned in the post. It just needs to be saved in xlsx format. df_submitted <- data.frame(x=c(1:20),y=c(0:1),z=c("R"))
df_submitted[[2,2]] <- 3
df_submitted[[5,2]] <- "yes"
df_submitted[[6,2]] <- "no"
df_submitted[[3,3]] <- "python"

Answer (score 1):

The `renderDT` module works for me, however there are a few other issues with your code:

- for `df_submitted`, it has to be uppercase Yes/No to match your rules
- when assigning values to a `reactiveValues` object, you don't need to use `<<-`, `<-` is enough
- I would also encapsulate the `dataTableProxy` into your module. I then store the changes in a `reactiveValues` object in the module and return this from the module, so that you can use it in the main

```
renderDTServer <- function(id,df) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input,output,session) {
    
    df_module <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
    observeEvent(df(), {
      df_module$data <- df()
    })
    
    output$dt_table=renderDT({
      df_dt <- df()
      visible_cols <- 1:((ncol(df_dt)/2))
      hidden_cols <- ((ncol(df_dt)/2)+1):ncol(df_dt)
      
      df_dt %>%
        datatable(
          editable="cell",
          selection="none",
          options=list(
            autoWidth=T,
            columnDefs=list(list(targets=hidden_cols,visible=F)))) %>%
        formatStyle(visible_cols,hidden_cols,
                    backgroundColor=styleEqual(c(0,1),c("white","#FFC7CE")),
                    color=styleEqual(c(0,1),c("black","#9C0006")))
    },server=T)
    
    dt_proxy <- dataTableProxy("dt_table")
    
    observeEvent(input$dt_table_cell_edit, {
      # browser()
      info <- input$dt_table_cell_edit
      df_module$data <- editData(df_module$data,info,dt_proxy)
    })
    
    return(df_module)
    
  })
}
```

- you can encapsulate the `validation` part in a function if you pass it the unevaluated reactive:

```
validation <- function(df){
  reactive({
    req(df$data)
    df_validate <- df$data
    ##rules
    rules <- validator(
      x>5,
      y<3,
      z=="R"
    )
    #Confront rules against df
    out <- confront(df_validate,rules)
    cells_dt <- data.frame(values(out))
    cells_dt <- cells_dt %>%
      mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(x==TRUE,0,1))
    #Join cells that fail the rules for future highlight in DT
    df_validate <- cbind(df_validate,cells_dt)
    df_validate
  })
}
```

and call it in the main app with

```
data_validated <- validation(df)
```

- you can encapsulate the observer as follows (only tested within one file though, not sure if it works with `global.R`):

```
check_for_replacement <- function(input, df, df_user_input) {
  observeEvent(input$lab_num,{
    browser()
    df$data <- df_user_input$data %>%
      mutate(y = case_when(
        y %in% df_match$lab ~ as.character(df_match$val[match(y,df_match$lab)]),
        TRUE~y))
  })
}
```

- for the `downExcelUnformat` module, you need to also use `output$download` in the `server` part (needs the same `id` as you've used in the `UI`  part)

```
downExcelUnformatServer <- function(id,filename,df) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input,output,session) {
    output$download <- downloadHandler(
      filename= filename,
      content=function(file){
        df_tbl <- df$data
        write.xlsx(df_tbl,file,rowNames=F)
      }) 
  })
}
```

Currently, the main `server` function looks like this. Please note that right now there is a circular dependency on the validate part and when you adjust the labels, the data is validated again, which adds another set of columns which are not dealt with. You need to think about what you want to do with these:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  
  #Upload file
  df_uploaded <- reactive({
    file_submitted <- input$df_submitted
    file_ext <- tools::file_ext(file_submitted$name)
    file_path <- file_submitted$datapath
    
    if (is.null(file_submitted)){
      return(NULL)
    } else if (file_ext=="xlsx"){
      read_xlsx(file_path,sheet=1)
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(df_uploaded(), {
    df$data <- df_uploaded()
  })
  
  #Function validate form, not working
  data_validated <- validation(df)
  
  #Module Render DT
  df_user_input <- renderDTServer("dt_data", data_validated)
  
  #Replace data matching a specific value
  #Would like to have this in a function outside app.R as well
  df_match <- data.frame(lab=c("Yes","No"),val=c(1,0))
  check_for_replacement(input, df, df_user_input)
  
  #Module download data
  downExcelUnformatServer("download_dt","form.xlsx",df_user_input)
}
```

Please only pass unevaluated reactives to modules and be aware that there is a difference between `reactive`/`reactiveVal`/`reactiveValues`. For a more detailed explanation, you can check out [my shiny modules tutorial](https://github.com/jonas-hag/structure_your_app).

Comment: Extremely thanks starja for the time in taking a look at my code! it was super helpful to solve the issues I had. In your example, I was not still able to make the modules entirely reactive. Because for example, the df edited in DT was not being evaluated again by the validation rules, and therefore the format was not changed in the the user edited the data with a valid value. However, I was able to solve this by accessing to df instead of df$data. But again, your answer was very helpful to get into an answer

Answer (score 0):

So, I kind of get into an answer. I just realized I was trying to pass the data into the modules using df$data when in reality what I needed was to pass just df. Now everything seems to work fine, at least for now....

So here is the module that is working for DT. As you may realize now I am passing three objects to the function the id, the df reactive object wihtout $data and df_val which is obtained from the validation function.

```
renderDTUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("dt_table"))
}


renderDTServer <- function(id,df,df_val) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input,output,session) {
    output$dt_table=renderDT({
      df_dt <- df_val()
      visible_cols <- 1:((ncol(df_dt)/2))
      hidden_cols <- ((ncol(df_dt)/2)+1):ncol(df_dt)
      
      df_dt %>%
        datatable(
          editable="cell",
          selection="none",
          options=list(
            autoWidth=T,
            columnDefs=list(list(targets=hidden_cols,visible=F)))) %>%
        formatStyle(visible_cols,hidden_cols,
                    backgroundColor=styleEqual(c(0,1),c("white","#FFC7CE")),
                    color=styleEqual(c(0,1),c("black","#9C0006")))
    },server=T)
    
    dt_proxy <- dataTableProxy("dt_table")
    
    observeEvent(input$dt_table_cell_edit, {
      info <- input$dt_table_cell_edit
      df$data <- editData(df$data,info,dt_proxy, resetPaging = FALSE)
    })
  
  })
}
```

For the download module is kind of the same:

```
downExcelUI <- function(id,label) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  downloadButton(ns("download"),label)
}

downExcelUnformatServer <- function(id,filename,df) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input,output,session) {
     output$download <- downloadHandler(
      filename=filename,
      content=function(file){
        df_tbl <- df$data
        write.xlsx(df_tbl,file,rowNames=F)
      })
  })
}
```

And here is the server part of the app:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  
  #Upload file
  df_uploaded <- reactive({
    file_submitted <- input$df_submitted
    file_ext <- tools::file_ext(file_submitted$name)
    file_path <- file_submitted$datapath

    if (is.null(file_submitted)){
      return(NULL)
    } else if (file_ext=="xlsx"){
      read_xlsx(file_path,sheet=1)
    }
  })

  observe({
    df$data <- df_uploaded()
  })
  
  # Function validate form
  data_validated <- validation(df)
  
   #Module Render DT
  renderDTServer("dt_data",df,data_validated)
  
  #Replace data matching a specific value
  df_match <- data.frame(lab=c("Yes","No"),val=c(1,0))
  replaceLabelServer("lab_num",df,df_match)

  
  #Module download data
  downExcelUnformatServer("download_dt","form.xlsx",df)
} #End server
```